# Jquery append column to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Using jQuery in a SharePoint environment, I am trying to append an object property as a last column of a table.

I am using the following JavaScript:

```
  var id = ctx.CurrentItem.ID; //Gets IDs for items in list
  console.log(id);
  $(".ms-vb-lastCell").append("<td role='gridcell' class='ms-vb-cellstyle ms-vb2'>" + id + "<td>")
```

The DOM tree for a table row:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class=" ms-itmHoverEnabled ms-itmhover" oncontextmenu="return ShowCallOutOrECBWrapper(this, event, false)" iid="244,1,0" id="244,1,0" role="row">
    <!--iid and id are dynamically generated on load-->
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">Completed</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">(2) Normal</td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2"><span class="ms-noWrap" title="3/30/2018">3/30/2018</span></td>
    <td role="gridcell" class="ms-vb-lastCell ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">
      <div style="background: #F3F3F3; display:block; height: 15px; width: 120px;">
        <div style="background: #00539B; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
      </div> 100 %
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I append each items id to the last `td` in each row.

Comment: Try referencing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: Closing `</td>` typo. You have just `<td>`. Also, `append` will put content inside selected item. You can't put `td` inside `td`. Use `after` for this case.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? showing a list's data in as a table ?
can you check your html as you are trying to put td inside td tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try looping in each tr then call `append` on that tr object.